# Excel count if sum of other values <0.5

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to count the number of employees that work less than 50% by department. Employees are identifiable by a number. One employee can have different jobs within a department made up of 3 times 20%.Therefore I first have to sum up the total work time per employee and then count how many work 50% or less. Since there are several thousands I want to do this with a formula per department. I can do it with sum if and count if but that would be one formula per employee. Is it possible to do it with one formula per department? Any help is much appreciated.
[mock up table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwmDn.png)
[solution with sum if and count if per employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBUhZ.png)
[Preferred solution, if possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fjy8.png)

| Employee_number | Department | Job_description | FTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Internal affairs | Research | 20% |
| 1 | Internal affairs | Administration | 20% |
| 1 | Human Resources | Management | 30% |
| 2 | Human Resources | Administration | 80% |
| 3 | External affairs | Research | 100% |
| 4 | Internal affairs | Management | 50% |
| 5 | Human Resources | Administration | 30% |
| 5 | Human Resources | Hiring | 40% |
| 6 | External affairs | Management | 100% |

mock up table

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would help if you could mock up some data showing a minimal example so we can copy paste and help create the formula.

Comment: It appears to me that you are looking for a pivot table.

Comment: Dhawal is correct. You can also do it with formulas but it won't be as easy to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Can you explain how to calculate FTE <50% per department with Pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite some ways to work on this, but in terms of readability maybe use  `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(B2:B10,N(D2:D10<0.5),SUM,,0)
```

---

Or, If one don't have access to the above mentioned functions in `Excel` as of yet and using `MS365` then could use the following:

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:D10,
     _department, INDEX(_data,,2),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_department),
     _counts, BYROW(_uniq,LAMBDA(b, SUM(--(b=_department)*(TAKE(_data,,-1)<0.5)))),
     VSTACK({"Department","Counts"},HSTACK(_uniq,_counts)))
```

---

Or, Using `MMULT()`

```
=LET(
     _dept, B2:B10,
     _fte, D2:D10<0.5,
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_dept,MMULT(N(_dept=TOROW(_dept)),--_fte))))
```

---

Or, Using `COUNTIFS()`

```
=LET(
     _dept, B2:B10,
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_dept, COUNTIFS(_dept,_dept,D2:D10,"<.5"))))
```

---

*There are many ways to work on this as you can see, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference.

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [FTE] < 0.5),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Department"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Dear Mayukh Bhattacharya, thank you so much for your help, amazing!